# convert jquery datatable date to specific format

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am working with MVC and jquery datatable plugin for grid purpose.
I am populating table in dynamically including table header and data. The column will be differ and I don't know what the column is coming and it's type.

In this case, Is there any option to change the date value to a specific format?

Just, populating table header as below,

```
<table class="display nowrap dataTable table reportData" id="reportsTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           @foreach (var row in Model.Columns)
            {
               <th>@row.Value</th>
             }
          </tr>

       </thead>

       <tbody>

       </tbody>
 </table>
```

And binding data as below,

```
var table = $('#reportsTable').DataTable();

$.ajax({
            url: urlContent + 'Reports/GetReportData',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#reportsTable_processing").css("visibility", "visible").css('display', 'block').css('z-index',1);
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                ErrorHandler(data, function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (ix, item) {
                        table.row.add(item);
                    });

                    table.columns.adjust().draw();
                });
            },
            complete: function () {
                $("#reportsTable_processing").css("visibility", "hidden").css('display', 'none');;
            }
        });
```

I need to change the date to a specific format (MM/DD/YYYY) wherever the date occurs in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<td>
   @row.value.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
</td>
```

in the *tbody*.